# Alter the definition of the Stored Computed Column in CockroachCloud

Tags: sql, calculated-columns, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I have stored computed column defined as:

```
ALTER TABLE computed_column AS INT col1+col2 STORED;
```

Is there way to change the calculation to `col1+col3` without first dropping the `computed_column`?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no way to change the expression of a computed column at this time.